# What should we say to a friend who has not seen each other for long time?

Tags: greetings

What should we say to a friend who has not seen each other for long time? is

> long time no see

an appropriate greeting?
What is native speakers' greeting in this circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **long time no see** is an appropriate phrase in the situation you described.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_time_no_see) or [TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Long+time+no+see)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! "Long time no see" is a very commonly used expression. I feel like it is often preceded by *hey*.

> Hey, long time no see!

But "hey" is optional.

Some alternatives include

> 1. (I) haven't seen you in days/weeks/months/years!
> 2. (I) haven't seen you in forever!
> 3. (I) haven't seen you in a long time!
> 4. (I) haven't seen you in ages!

You can also replace "haven't seen you in" with "It's been". For example, if you haven't seen your friend Michael in a very long time, you might say

> Michael, it's been a long time!